# How to delete item from Swift UI List in UI Test

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xctest

### Is it possible to delete a Swift UI List item from a UI test?

For the user they can press the edit button which puts the list into edit mode (screenshot 1), then press the red circle with the white line, then press Delete.

Alternatively the user can swipe delete the list item.

---

Even with the accessibility inspector on I can't see what the icon is (the red circle with the white line). It doesn't show anything when I hover over it. Also the recorder doesn't record anything if I try using that tool.

If I try with `.swipeLeft()` to try to delete using the swipe gesture instead, it actually "taps" on the list button instead of swiping and just opens the detail view.

Any ideas? What am I missing here? Or is this not actually possible?

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a way to make it work with the swipe method. It's pretty simple. Just need to let the test know to swipe a bit slower.

```
app.staticTexts["Test"].swipeLeft(velocity: XCUIGestureVelocity.slow)
```

Using that I'm able to then tap on the delete button and assert that the item is gone.

I'm not super fussed right now about the other method, as long as there's a way to test deleting (and as long as I'm allowing swipe delete). However would be good to know if someone has the answer.

Comment: you're a genius.  Its weird that the other trick was to do `staticTexts` instead of accessing the cells too.. Weird that it works with static texts but not cells.